# Shim Twitter Bootstrap for RequireJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

The RequireJS [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#ieloadfail) say that to support older versions of IE, you need to configure `enforceDefine: true`.

> So if you want to support Internet Explorer, catch load errors, and have modular code either through direct define() calls or shim config, always set enforceDefine to be true. See the next section for an example.
>
> NOTE: If you do set enforceDefine: true, and you use data-main="" to load your main JS module, then that main JS module must call define() instead of require() to load the code it needs. The main JS module can still call require/requirejs to set config values, but for loading modules it should use define().

Since Twitter Bootstrap isn't an AMD module, I need to shim it for it to work.
This is how I configure it;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var require = {
        paths: {
            "bootstrap": "../bootstrap",
            "jquery": "../jquery-1.8.2"
        },
        shim: {
            "bootstrap": ["jquery"]
        },
        enforceDefine: true
    };
</script>
```

Later when my module wants bootstrap as a dependency, I still end up with an error message;

```
Error: No define call for bootstrap
```

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine

If I've understood the docs correctly, `enforceDefine`should ignore shims but it's not.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the docs that error is thrown if "Script was part of a shim config that specified a global string property that can be checked for loading, and that check failed."

To fix this you need to add exports value in the shim config so that RequireJS can check whether the script was succesfully loaded. In case of Bootstrap that's slightly tricky as Bootstrap doesn't 'export' a propert global variable only a bunch of jquery plugins, but you can use any of those plugins as an export value e.g. `$.fn.popover`:

```
{
    paths: {
        "bootstrap": "../bootstrap",
        "jquery": "../jquery-1.8.2"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
          deps: ["jquery"],
          exports: "$.fn.popover"
        }
    },
    enforceDefine: true
}
```

Comment: For those of us new to JS how would you then use the popover in your own code?  With require I can say "var $ = require('jquery') would I write "var popover = require("$.fn.popover")?

Comment: No. The require takes module path in the filesystem as an argument. You can only do require("bootstrap") in this case and then just use it $("#example").popover(). You could require individual bootstrap plugins if you used the unconcatenated versions, but that would require more setup. In general jQuery plugins that attach themselves to $.fn are not very compatible with the CJS/AMD module philosophy.

Comment: What if you need to access multiple plugins? Is there a way to have multiple exports with requirejs? or would you have multiple shims for each plugin? or something else?

Comment: Bootstrap extends jQuery (and $) so in the 'exports' you could use simply '$' (i've been using it that way) Also I think the 'exports' value could be a function in which you could group all the bootstrap plugins in a new namespace. I haven't try that yet.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of doing the magic with shim, I converted the bootstrap JS into a module:

```
define([ "jquery" ], function($) {
  // bootstrap JS code
});
```

Everything else I found in the forums and on stackoverflow did not work for me because I get jQuery from the CDN. I assume because I hit the issue as described in the requireJS doc on http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

> Do not mix CDN loading with shim config in a build. Example scenario:
>   you load jQuery from the CDN but use the shim config to load something
>   like the stock version of Backbone that depends on jQuery. When you do
>   the build, be sure to inline jQuery in the built file and do not load
>   it from the CDN. Otherwise, Backbone will be inlined in the built file
>   and it will execute before the CDN-loaded jQuery will load. This is
>   because the shim config just delays loading of the files until
>   dependencies are loaded, but does not do any auto-wrapping of define.
>   After a build, the dependencies are already inlined, the shim config
>   cannot delay execution of the non-define()'d code until later.
>   define()'d modules do work with CDN loaded code after a build because
>   they properly wrap their source in define factory function that will
>   not execute until dependencies are loaded. So the lesson: shim config
>   is a stop-gap measure for for non-modular code, legacy code.
>   define()'d modules are better.

Converting the bootstrap into a ordinary AMD module and removing the shim config solved it for me. Only drawback: you cannot retrieve bootstrap from the bootstrap CDN.

Comment: Then again it's probably better not to use the CDN bootstrap since it doesn't allow you to run the Closure Compiler to eliminate unused functions, etc.

Comment: Note, the current version of Bootstrap 3 references jQuery not $, so now you actually have to pass in: `define('bootstrap', ['jquery'], function(jQuery) {`

Answer (score 11):

I use this configuration inside my project:

**startup.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        /* other paths are omitted */
        'bootstrap': '../libs/bootstrap'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-slider': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.slider' }, 
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-affix': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.affix' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-alert': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.alert' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-button': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.button' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.carousel' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.collapse' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.dropdown' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-modal': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.modal' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-popover': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.popover' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.scrollspy'        },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-tab': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.tab' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.tooltip' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-transition': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.support.transition' },
        'bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.typeahead'  },
    }
});

require(['domReady', 'app'], function(domReady, app) {
    domReady(function() {
        app.init();
    });
});
```

then in my code I use this:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/photos-list.html'], function($, _, Backbone, html) {
    var PhotosListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        viewImageFullscreen: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            require(['bootstrap/bootstrap-modal', 'text!templates/photo-modal.html'], function(modal, htmlModal) {
                 var modalTemplate = _.template(htmlModal, options);
                 $('body').append(modalTemplate);

                 // setup
                 $(selector + '_modal').modal({
                     backdrop: true,
                     keyboard: true,
                     show: false
                 }).css({
                     'width': function() { return ($(document).width() * 0.55) + 'px'; },
                     'margin-left': function() { return -($(this).width() * 0.5); }
                 });

                 // trigger `modal` 
                 $(selector + '_modal').modal('show');
             }); // require() call
         // ...
```

Comment: I like this approach, here are the updated shims for bootstrap 3 - https://gist.github.com/benfoxall/8844292

Comment: @benjaminbenben recently I've found this cool resource: http://matznermatzner.de/en/bernd/2013/11/loading-non-amd-modules-requirejs-part-1-jquery-ui

Comment: and this one: http://matznermatzner.de/en/bernd/2013/12/loading-non-amd-modules-requirejs-part-2-zurb-foundation

Comment: Though they are about *Zurb Foundation* / *JQuery UI* they're really worth reading!

Comment: those are brilliant, thanks for sharing.  Such a better way to use those libraries; you'll be able to create an optimised build from the start - rather than retrospectively optimising. [JQuery itself](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/jquery.js) uses AMD now - would be crazy awesome to be able to hook into that.

Answer (score 4):

@lexeme & @benjaminbenben how about wrapping this concept in a RequireJS plugin which creates the shim, requires jQuery and also returns jQuery so you wouldn't need to include this manually?

To use a bootstrap component you would simply use:

```
define(['bootstrap!tooltip'], function($){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

And you would use this [require-bootstrap-plugin](https://gist.github.com/jbmoelker/b8c3c4359db7ca94439f#file-bootstrap-js) to make it work.

Comment: This is pretty slick. However, use caution because if a plugin has dependencies, this won't work. For example, popover requires tooltip.