# Getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on doc ready

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

I am trying to add bootstrap.js to my require config. Every ~20th refresh or so, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error on line 23, which is my doc ready: `$(function () {`

I read [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377373/shim-twitter-bootstrap-for-requirejs), which lead me to set the require.config below.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    templates: '../templates',
    bootstrap: 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap'
  },
  shim: {
      backbone: {
          deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
          exports: 'Backbone'
      },
      underscore: {
          exports: '_'
      },
      bootstrap: {
          deps: ['jquery'],
          exports: "$.fn.popover"
      },
      enforceDefine: true
  }

});

require([
  'ripple',    
], function(Ripple){
    Ripple.initialize();
});
```

### ripple.js

```
// Filename: ripple.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'router', // Request router.js
  'bootstrap'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Router, Bootstrap) {
    var initialize = function () {
        // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
        Router.initialize();
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

I'm assuming this is a race condition that bootstrap is occasionally losing. Any ideas?