# Using Twitter Bootstrap with requireJS - undefined is not a function`

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, undefined, amd

After doing some reading of the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377373/shim-twitter-bootstrap-for-requirejs) I wrapped my compiled bootstrap JS plugin file in an AMD module like so:

```
define(['zepto'], function($){ ...Bootstrap pasted here... });
```

Then this is what my *main.js* file looks like for config:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        'zepto': 'lib/zepto',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'text': 'lib/text',
        'bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap'
    },
    shim: {
        'zepto': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['zepto', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
require([
    'app',
    'zepto',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'bootstrap'
    ],
    function(App){
        //start the app
        App.initialize();
});
```

But in the console i am getting the following error in the *bootstrap.js* file:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It seems $ is not defined even though it is being passed into the module.  The full wrapped bootstrap module is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2tQdS/).

Am using zepto which is supposed to be compatible with Bootstrap and am exporting $ from the shim so cannot see why this is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following lines of code in the bootstrap JS file.

Where `window.jQuery` is passed into the functions modified this to include the Zepto global object also like so `window.jQuery || window.Zepto`

More information here:

[Zepto with Bootstrap](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/commit/1d5daef9f8abd9b92340c135bfbb11a7ce1a83a6)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `define(['zepto'], function($){ ...Bootstrap pasted here... });`, you can just replace all `window.jQuery` in the function invoke call with `$`.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem.  I added a shim for bootsrap and it seems to work now.  This would be in addition to your other shims.

```
shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['zepto']
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit the bootstrap JS file, it might be worth considering this shim, it should set the jQuery object before bootstrap loads.

```
  'zepto': {
    exports: '$',
    init: function() {
      window.jQuery = $;
    }
  }
```