# Can't load Bootstrap with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

I can't seem to figure out how to load Bootstrap via RequireJS. None of the examples that I found worked for me.

Here is my shim:

```
require.config({
  // Sets the js folder as the base directory for all future relative paths
  baseUrl: "./js",
  urlArgs: "bust=" +  (new Date()).getTime(),
  waitSeconds: 200,
  // 3rd party script alias names (Easier to type "jquery" than "libss/jquery, etc")
  // probably a good idea to keep version numbers in the file names for updates checking
  paths: {

      // Core libsraries
      // --------------
      "jquery": "libs/jquery",
      "underscore": "libs/lodash",
      "backbone": "libs/backbone",
      "marionette": "libs/backbone.marionette",

      // Plugins
      // -------
      "bootstrap": "libs/plugins/bootstrap",
      "text": "libs/plugins/text",
      "responsiveSlides": "libs/plugins/responsiveslides.min",
      'googlemaps': 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDdqRFLz6trV6FkyjTuEm2k-Q2-MjZOByM&sensor=false',


      // Application Folders
      // -------------------
      "collections": "app/collections",
      "models": "app/models",
      "routers": "app/routers",
      "templates": "app/templates",
      "views": "app/views",
      "layouts": "app/layouts",
      "configs": "app/config"

  },

  // Sets the configuration for your third party scripts that are not AMD compatible
  shim: {

      "responsiveSlides": ["jquery"],
      "bootstrap": ["jquery"],
      "backbone": {

        // Depends on underscore/lodash and jQuery
        "deps": ["underscore", "jquery"],

        // Exports the global window.Backbone object
        "exports": "Backbone"

      },
      "marionette": {
        // Depends on underscore/lodash and jQuery
        "deps": ["backbone", "underscore", "jquery"],
        // Exports the global window.Backbone object
        "exports": "Marionette"
      },
      'googlemaps': { 'exports': 'GoogleMaps' },
      // Backbone.validateAll plugin that depends on Backbone
      "backbone.validate": ["backbone"]

  },
  enforceDefine: true

});
```

and here is how I call Bootstrap:

```
define([
        "jquery",
        "underscore",
        "backbone",
        "marionette",

        "collections/Navigations",
        'bootstrap',
        ],
function($, _, Backbone, Marionette, Navigations, Bootstrap){
```

The error that I get is this:

```
Uncaught Error: No define call for bootstrap
```

Any ideas on how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found a working example here:

https://github.com/sudo-cm/requirejs-bootstrap-demo

I followed it to get my code to work.

According to that demo, especially [app.js](https://github.com/sudo-cm/requirejs-bootstrap-demo/blob/master/assets/js/app.js), you simply make a shim to catch Bootstrap's dependency on jQuery,

```
requirejs.config({
    // pathsオプションの設定。"module/name": "path"を指定します。拡張子（.js）は指定しません。
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/jquery-1.8.3.min",
        "jquery.bootstrap": "lib/bootstrap.min"
    },
    // shimオプションの設定。モジュール間の依存関係を定義します。
    shim: {
        "jquery.bootstrap": {
            // jQueryに依存するのでpathsで設定した"module/name"を指定します。
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});
```

and then mark Bootstrap as a dependency of the app itself, so that it loads before `app.js`.

```
// require(["module/name", ...], function(params){ ... });
require(["jquery", "jquery.bootstrap"], function ($) {
    $('#myModalButton').show();
});
```

Finally, since `app.js` is the data-main,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/require.min.js" data-main="./assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

Bootstrap's JS is guaranteed to load before any application code.

Comment: This do not works for me with IE 11. If I load the page with dev tool open, it works.

Answer (score 12):

Bootstrap lib does not return any object like jQuery, Underscore or Backbone: this script just modifies the jQuery object with the addition of new methods. So, if you want to use the Bootstrap library, you just have to add in the modules and use the jquery method as usual (without declarating Bootstrap like param, because the value is `undefined`):

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "marionette",
    "collections/Navigations",
    "bootstrap",
    ],

function($,_,Backbone,Marionette,Navigations){
    $("#blabla").modal("show"); //Show a modal using Bootstrap, for instance
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping on this. I tried this before I posted the question and I tried it again now - it does not work. The page wont load, but no error in the console. Any other suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Now I added "enforceDefine: true" and I get the following error "No define call for libs/plugins/bootstrap" but the path is correct. So, I dont really know where to go from here.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377373/shim-twitter-bootstrap-for-requirejs will help with the enforceDefine error

Comment: @Andrew I found this, but it didn't help me at all. Still looking for  a solution to this.

Comment: Could you reduce your problem in a simpler JsFiddle? Without a complete code, we cannot see all the context. Maybe there is another trouble.

Comment: Per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34266969/712526), there's no guarantee that jQuery will load before Bootstrap in your example, because neither is a dependency of the other. However, you can make a [shim](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to specify bootstrap's dependencies, to guarantee they all load first.

Answer (score 8):

I found it was sufficient to add the following to my requirejs.config call (pseudocode):

```
requirejs.config({
  ...
  shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to use Require.Js **ORDER** plugin, what it does? Simply loads all your Libraries in order, in this case you won't get any errors, ohh and bootstrap depends on **jQuery**, so we need to use **shim** in this case:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "./assets",
    paths: {
        order: '//requirejs.org/docs/release/1.0.5/minified/order',
        jquery: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min',
        bootstrap: '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': { 
            deps:['jquery']
        }
    }
});

require(['order!jquery', 'order!bootstrap'], function($) {

});
```