# how to jquery and bootstrap file using in requirejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

```
define(["jquery","bootstrap","jquery.min"],function($){
    var inittest = function(){
        alert("hello");
    }
    var init = function(){
        inittest();
    };
    return {
        init: init
    }
});
```

It's not working. How to use jQuery to define array?

Comment: This thread on [how to load Bootstrap with requirejs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16259098/2672370) should be helpful. You need to shim bootstrap. Look at the first answer there for the details.

Comment: how to use jquery.min file work with this code?

Comment: Requirejs doesn't care whether your jquery is minified or not, so choose one of the two and then load it in `requirejs.config`. Did you read the top answer I linked to above?

Comment: i want another one example.please send another one example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things here (the details are in [the useful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16259098/2672370) I linked you to, so please read).

1. *Configure* requirejs so that when you declare modules (e.g. "jquery", "bootstrap"), requirejs can resolve them to actual files, minified or otherwise.
2. *Shim* bootstrap by specifying jquery as its dependency, so that jquery is loaded before it.

To accomplish these, make a call to `requirejs.config({...})` with the appropriate options ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458857/2672370) is an example). The use case there is exactly the same as yours: jquery is specified as a bootstrap dependency by shimming bootstrap. There you will also see  an example of how to tell requirejs where your files are (this is accomplished via the `paths` property). Note how the *.js* extension is not explicitly specified there; do the same.

Needless to say, configuring requirejs can get complicated, but the basic idea is there, configure it by specifying the base directory and where the files are to be found, then shim non-AMD modules. An important thing to be aware of is that bootstrap is going to be what's called a *declarative module*, which means that it's only used for its *side-effects* (viz. for what changes it makes to `$`).