# Scripts Dependencies Using RequireJS Shim

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm upgrading from jQuery 1.8 to 1.9 and since jQuery.browser() is removed, I will use [jQuery Browser Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/).

My requirejs config file (loaded using data-main="") looks somewhat like this:

(**EDITED** - added more code snippets)

**main-comp.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery1.9.1.min',
        utils: 'modules/utils',
        myController: "controllers/myController",
        browserPlugin: 'libs/jquery/jquery.browser.min'
    },
    shim: {
        browserPlugin: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

require(['myController', 'jquery'], function (controller, $) {
        $(controller.start);
    }
);
```

**moduls/utils.js**

```
define(['browserPlugin'], function () {
    return {
        browser: $.browser
    };
});
```

**myController.js**

```
define(['utils'], function (utils) {
    function start() {
        console.log(utils.browser.msie)
    }
    return {
        start: start
    };
});
```

Everything seemed to work properly, but then I saw that **sometimes** in **IE only** I get a `'jQuery' is undefined` (it's a capital Q there) or `'$' is undefined` errors from  the `jquery.browser.min.js` file.

I thought the `deps` means that jquery will load before the jquery.browser file but apparently this isn't always the case. I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377373/shim-twitter-bootstrap-for-requirejs#13556882) and add `exports: "$.fn.browser"` but with no success.

When running an optimized version (minify+uglify using r.js) I haven't encountered it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure you reference `$` as a parameter in the `require` callback. Like so:

```
require(['myController', 'jquery'], function (controller, $) {
        $(controller.start);
    }
);
```

This ensures that jQuery is available to use. It is a bit of an odd one as it will expose itself globally anyway so it will sometimes work regardless, but the correct way is to explicitly require it and use it inside the callback as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't help and I'm still getting these error (on IE, not always). I'm editing my question to give more details.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing jquery dependency in **moduls/utils.js**, please try:

```
define(['jquery', 'browserPlugin'], function ($) {
  return {
    browser: $.browser
  };
});
```

and also, just to be on the safe side, add jquery to your shim :

```
jquery: {
  exports: "$"
},
```

By the way, why don't you use $.browser in your code and just load the jquery plugin using the shim configuration?

Comment: I still encounter the same problem... Can't tell what's wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the script in `data-main` is loading asynchronously, that means that it may load **after** the scripts it defines.

The solution is to load another script with the `require.config` right after the `require.js` script.

[data-main Entry Point Documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main).