# Delete unused shim config in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, gruntjs, shim

OK, so my problem is that I'd like to be able to automatically delete parts of the shim config I've set up for RequireJS; rather than loading the entire minified Bootstrap file I split it up into the different plugins, so that I get the benefit of less filesize when my application uses less of the Bootstrap components. E.g:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        jquery     : 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min',
        bootstrap  : 'vendor/bootstrap-sass/js'
    },
    shim : {
        'bootstrap/affix': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.affix' },
        'bootstrap/alert': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.alert' },
        'bootstrap/button': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.button' },
        'bootstrap/carousel': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.carousel' },
        'bootstrap/collapse': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.collapse' },
        'bootstrap/dropdown': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.dropdown' },
        'bootstrap/modal': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.modal' },
        'bootstrap/popover': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.popover' },
        'bootstrap/scrollspy': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.scrollspy'        },
        'bootstrap/tab': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.tab' },
        'bootstrap/tooltip': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.fn.tooltip' },
        'bootstrap/transition': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$.support.transition' },
    }
});
```

Whilst the `r.js` optimizer correctly identifies that I'm only using `bootstrap/dropdown`, it still includes the shim config for files that don't end up in the production code. So my question is can I get rid of the unused shim files automatically? I'm using `grunt-contrib-requirejs` for the actual optimization and have had no problems with that. A Grunt based solution would be preferable but I'm open to anything else. Thanks.

Comment: just curious... why? Isn't it just 12 (or less) lines

Comment: And ~700 bytes of code, yes, but in an "optimised" JavaScript payload that's around 550KB (bootstrap, requirejs, underscore, backbone, d3, jquery plus custom code) anything I can do to reduce the filesize is worth doing.

Comment: So, to reduce your code a little bit, why don't you remove the `exports` from each jQuery plugin? It seems useless to me.

Comment: I put that in because of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377373/shim-twitter-bootstrap-for-requirejs that said I needed to define an exports variable. OK, so that would reduce the code quite a lot, is there any way to get rid of the rest of it as per my original question? ;-)

Comment: ~700 bytes of text gzipped is like ~175 bytes. Use your time for actual improvement. If the size is really a matter, start by modularizing your code so you load less in the initial payload; that'll bring real improvement. Saving bytes is completely useless and won't be noticed by anyone.

Comment: On a side note, R.js don't change the config to remove "unused" settings because it can't know if you'll load some of them at run time. If it did, it could break people code.

Comment: Might want to look at this: https://github.com/gfranko/amdclean It'll remove all the AMD config overload, you need to restrict some AMD patterns in your code, but it may fits your need.

Comment: Simon, if you can write your comments up into an answer I'll accept it. Thank you kindly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the great points made above, and hopefully close the question

- Unused shim configs are not removed by r.js since it can't know if you need them at run-time
- ~175 bytes (gzipped) are not worth manually optimizing, especially as part of a payload 200 times that big, and won't cause noticeable improvement
- [AMDClean](https://github.com/gfranko/amdclean) could be an automated way to de-AMDify your scripts completely and thus meet your size-saving desires

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. :-)